# How to play the default caller tune sound....?

Tags: android

I am making a calling app and while the user is waiting for the call to connect, I want to play the default sound which is played when we call someone and wait for the correspondent to pick up.

Comment: You can try the available default tones in ToneGenerator class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible as such.

You are talking about the [ringing tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_tone), also called ringback tone sometimes. It is not generated by the Android system, but the switching system, so you don't have access to it from the API.

To include that sound in your app, you have to include an asset for that sound (mp3).

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement `RingtoneManager` for play default ringtone of system, have look

```
Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this,uri);
ringtone.play();
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Thanks for replying But, This is playing RingTone but I want callerTone

Comment: i don't think to it will be achieve.